# i want to remove timestamp using flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, datetime

The end date comes like `2022-11-02 00:00:00.000` how to remove this timestamp

```dart
 onPressed: () async {
                      String startDate = startDateController.text;

                      String duration = durationController.text;

                      final int dur = int.parse(durationController.text);

                      var stDate = DateTime.parse(startDateController.text);

                      final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
                      final String formatted = formatter.format(stDate);
                      print(formatted);

                      DateTime thirtyDaysFromNow =
                          stDate.add(new Duration(days: dur));

                      setState(() {
                        startDate;
                        duration;
                        // endDateController.text =
                        //     formatted.thirtyDaysFromNow.toString();

                        endDateController.text = thirtyDaysFromNow.toString();
                      });

                      //print(thirtyDaysFromNow);
                    },
                    child: const Text("Save"),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168))),
                  ))
```

Comment: You like to get only date part? Your formatter is Ok, can  you include text instead of `startDateController`... data?

Answer (score 0):

The `stDate` formatter is working fine. You can format the end data before adding on controller,

Your formatter

```dart
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

And while adding text to the controller

```dart
DateTime thirtyDaysFromNow = DateTime.parse(startDate);
endDateController.text = formatter.format(thirtyDaysFromNow);
```

Comment: i want to implement This code in Edit page in start date picker and end date picker how to do this

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. But I think you can use this formatter before assigning and showing on UI

Comment: i want to implement    this code in edit page for calculating end date       String startDate = startDateController.text;

                String duration = durationController.text;

                final int dur = int.parse(durationController.text);

                var stDate = DateTime.parse(startDateController.text);

                final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
                final String formatted = formatter.format(stDate);                              
                DateTime thirtyDaysFromNow = stDate.add(Duration(days: dur));

Comment: and what do you get expect from and what you are getting.  if this is the part of current question, you can click on edit button and update the question, if new you can create another one. Please consider including full minimal snippet

Comment: i want to when i select start date the end date automatically comes using months like 12, 24, 36, 48 in flutter flutter

Answer (score 0):

I simulated it here for you, try it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class DateCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  const DateCustom({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DateCustom> createState() => _DateCustomState();
}

class _DateCustomState extends State<DateCustom> {
  TextEditingController startDateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController durationController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController endDateController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DateCustom'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: startDateController,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: durationController,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: endDateController,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String startDate = startDateController.text;

                String duration = durationController.text;

                final int dur = int.parse(durationController.text);

                var stDate = DateTime.parse(startDateController.text);

                final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
                final String formatted = formatter.format(stDate);

                //avoid print();
                debugPrint(formatted);

                DateTime thirtyDaysFromNow = stDate.add(Duration(days: dur));

                setState(() {
                  startDate;
                  duration;

                  endDateController.text = formatter
                      .format(DateTime.parse(thirtyDaysFromNow.toString()));
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Date')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

input:
2022-10-18
5
output: Must be -> 2022-10-23

Comment: i want to when i select start date the end date automatically comes using months like 12, 24, 36, 48 in flutter